# Python: "FileNotFoundError" Despite being able to print such files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a Python3 script where the code walks through directories and sub-directories to pull out all gzipped warc files. 
I'd like to also add that the files are not in my home directory

```
file_path = os.path.join('/nappa7/pip73/Service')   
walk_file(parallel_bulk, file_path)
```

Perhaps python is not looking where i think it's looking, nevertheless, here is my walk_file functions:

```
def walk_file(bulk, file_path): 
warc = warcat.model.WARC()
try:
    for (file_path,dirs,files) in os.walk(file_path):
        for filenames in files:
            if filenames.endswith('.warc.gz'):
                warc.load(filenames)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

When I replace the warc.load(filenames) with a print statement like so:

```
            if filenames.endswith('.warc.gz'):
                print(filenames)
```

The filenames are printed out onto the console as expected. Therefore, It leads me to believe that python was able to succesfully locate all warc.gz files. However, when i try the warc.load(filenames), i get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Sample.warc.gz'
```

I can certainly use some guidance. 
Thank you.

---

So for anyone else who has a similar issue:
changing the code to this worked:

```
warc.load(os.path.join(file_path, filenames))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `os.path.join(file_path, filenames)` instead of just `filenames`.

Otherwise the operating system will look for the file in the current directory instead of `file_path`.

(And why is `filenames` plural when it refers to a single filename?)

Comment: filenames refers to all files that end with warc.gz., Thus, I'm expecting more than one file. I shall try your approach